# Why verilog simulators model net delay as inertial delay rather than transport delay?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm connecting a DDR model in the test bench using wires with net delay to model the trace delay on the board. The trace can hold 1 or 2 bits in its transmission line, but because the simulators models the net delay as inertial delay, all the bits get filtered out as glitches. I don't even get the clock this way. The SystemVerilog spec is not explicit on this subject. So, I'm guessing that the simulators don't want to incur the cost on performance and storage to model it as transport delay. However, I strongly believe transport delay is the right way to use for net delay, because otherwise the hassle of modeling each bidir signal with its own delay is huge. What do you think?

Here's my test case.

```
`timescale 1ps/1ps

module sim_top  ();

parameter realtime NET_DELAY = 80ps;
parameter realtime PULSE_DELAY = 50ps;

logic driver;
initial begin
  driver = 0;
  forever #PULSE_DELAY driver = !driver;
end

wire #NET_DELAY a;
assign a = driver;
always @(posedge a or negedge a) begin
  $display("a=%b @ %t", a, $time);
end

logic b;
always @(*) begin
  b <= #NET_DELAY driver;
end

always @(posedge b or negedge b) begin
  $display("b=%b @ %t", b, $time);
end


initial begin
 #1ns;
 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

> So, I'm guessing that the simulators don't want to incur the cost on performance and storage to model it as transport delay.

I can imagine how you got that reasoning. From what I have learned, your assumptions is incorrect.

Real logic gates have inertial delay. This delay is caused by RC (resistance & capacitance) that is inherit to the device, from routing, or intentionally added. Verilog uses inertial delay to emulate delay behavior of real logic.

I cannot find a citation, but from discussions with engineers with pre-Verilog experience, early Verilog only modeled gates (think Verilog primitives `and`,`or`,`nand`,`bufif0`, etc.). Assign statements and always blocks were added some time later along with the possibility of synthesis. Non-blocking (`<=`) assignments were added much later (and copied from VHDL from what I've heard), but sill before Verilog by IEEE.

Assign statement handle delay the same way as gates. See [IEEE1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 10.3.3 *Continuous assignment delays*

> A delay given to a continuous assignment shall specify the time duration between a right-hand operand value change and the assignment made to the left-hand side. If the left-hand references a scalar net, then the ***delay shall be treated in the same way as for gate delays***; that is, different delays can be given for the output rising, falling, and changing to high impedance (see 28.16).

I'm guessing assign statements use the same type of delay as gates to reuse existing code (inside the simulator, not Verilog code) for managing delay and maintains continuity for the definition of delay. It also mapping easier, ex: `assign #1 out = in;` is the same as `buf #1 (out,in);`.

With real circuits, when you want a delay of 10 with a filter of 0.5, you need chain of 20 delay cells with small RC. If you want a delay and filter of 10 you use one delay cell with large RC. In theory synthesizers could use this delay information for target delay and filtration control (I cannot think of any synthesizer that actually does this; all synthesizers I know of ignore RTL delays).

Generally non-blocking (`<=`) assignments are used for synchronous logic (edge-sensitive flops and level-sensitive latches). Transport delay is the main exception but should only be used for behavioral modeling that will not be synthesized. If you know the amount of filtering your real delay path will have, I suggest coding it as follows:

```
reg out;
wire #(FILTER) in_filtered = in;
always @* out <= #(TOTAL_DELAY-FILTER) in_filter; // must be >=0.0
```

Which is cleaner and less CPU intensive then the pure inertial delay approach:

```
localparam LENGTH = TOTAL_DELAY/FILTER; // must be an integer >=2
wire out;
wire [LENGTH-2 : 0] delay_chain;
assign #(FILTER) {out,delay_chain} = {delay_chain,in};
```

Comment: I agree with everything you mentioned here. I still have this question: If the delay in a continuous assign statement is for conbinational gates, then why do we need the net delay to do the same thing? The IEEE1800-2012 § 10.3.3 also says: 
wire #10 wireA; This syntax, called a net delay, means that any value change that is to be applied to wireA by some other statement shall be delayed for ten time units before it takes effect.

Specifying the delay in a continuous assignment that is part of the net declaration shall be treated differently from specifying a net delay and then making a ...

Comment: The creators of Verilog decided to make these three statements behaviorally equivalent: `wire #10 wireA; assign wireA = wireB;` , `wire wireA; assign #10 wireA = wireB;` , and `wire #10 wireA = wireB;`. However there is another option for both to have the delay. For example: `wire #6 wireA; assign #4 wireA = wireB;` This basically creates an invisible net equivalent to `wire #6 wireA; wire #4 invisibleBdly4 = wireB; assign wireA = invisibleBdly4;`. I'm guessing they wanted it to be flexible. In practice, I have never seen the delay used on in the declaration and the assignment.

Comment: Well, they are equivalent when it's a single-driver wire. When there are multiple drivers on the net, the net delay should model when any assignment takes effect on top of the gate delay. I think that should be transport, not inertial, in nature. I just want something that makes my life easier when modeling the delay of a bi-directional PCB trace with pulldown in my test bench.

Comment: Your original question did not mention a desire bidirectional transport delay. It asked why Verilog uses inertial delay as default. How to model bidirectional transport delay is a good, _separate_,  question. Good enough [I asked and answered it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47820470/1959732) . I'll leave it open a few days to see if there is a better answer. If my answer here satisfies your "why is net delay inertial", then please vote and/or accept click the accept answer icon.

Answer (score 0):

Transport delay could be simulated by using #delays with non-blocking assighments:

```
always @*
   out <= #delay input;
```

this is close to an inertial delay:

```
assign
    #delay out = input;
```

The rest are mostly behavioral simulation artifacts which should be used in testbench only.

I had found this paper very informative for this issue:
http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs152/fa06/handouts/CummingsHDLCON1999_BehavioralDelays_Rev1_1.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, that's not what I'm asking. Actually your answer shows exactly what the problem is. Think about how you would use your method to model the delay on a bi-dir wire. Do you think the net delay should be modeled as transport delay instead of inertial delay to may our lives easier?