# How to model bidirectional transport delay

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

For example: IOs A and B are connected have a 10ns io-to-io delay between them. The IOs run at 500MHz (2ns period).

By default Verilog uses inertial delay which acts as a filter. Therefore defining the interconnect wire as `wire #(10ns) io;` will not work since it will filter out the data.

```
wire #(10ns) io;

assign io = io_a_en ? a_data_500MHz : 'z;
assign io = io_b_en ? b_data_500MHz : 'z;
```

Transport delay is unidirectional. Creating one for each direction on an IO will cause multiple drivers and a feedback loop.

```
always @(a) b_reg <= #(10ns) a;
always @(b) a_reg <= #(10ns) b;
assign a = b_reg; // feedback b_reg = b = a_reg = a ... and multi-driver
assign b = a_reg; // feedback a_reg = a = b_reg = b ... and multi-driver

assign a = io_a_en ? a_data_500MHz : 'z;
assign b = io_b_en ? b_data_500MHz : 'z;
```

How should one model bidirectional transport delay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bidirectional transport delay can be achieved using driver strength with the two uni-directional transport delay. The model should assign the nets to a weaker drive strength the the IO drivers. This will give priority to the real driver and prevent driver conflict.

To prevent a feedback loop, use the drive strength as the qualifier to decide if the transport delay should assign the source value or high-Z. An easy way to determine the drive strength is with with `%v`, see [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 21.2.1.5 *Strength format*

```
module bidi_delay #( parameter INERTIAL=0, TRANSPORT=10 ) (
    inout a, b
  );

  reg a2b, b2a;
  reg [23:0] a_strength, b_strength;

  always @(a) begin
    $sformat(a_strength, "%v", a);
    a2b <= #(TRANSPORT) (a_strength[23:16] == "S") ? a : 1'bz;
  end
  always @(b) begin
    $sformat(b_strength, "%v", b);
    b2a <= #(TRANSPORT) (b_strength[23:16] == "S") ? b : 1'bz;
  end

  assign (weak0,weak1) #(INERTIAL) a = b2a;
  assign (weak0,weak1) #(INERTIAL) b = a2b;
endmodule
```

Tested on [EDAplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2LZF) with Aldec Riviera, Icarus Verilog, and GPL Cver

Answer (score 0):

I have researched the solutions from Greg and the solution in the article https://www.fpgarelated.com/showthread/comp.arch.fpga/58894-1.php. Both of these solutions have a common disadvantage: there is not taken into account the strength of io. For example Solution of Greg reduces signal strength to Weak and if IO is not "Strong"or"Supply" then the code above is not worked.

Therefore I try to write my own solution.

```
module via_d (inout l, r, input bit en);
  timeunit 1ps;
  timeprecision 100fs;
  
  const bit[2:0] assoc_strn2int [bit[15:0]]='{ "Hi":0, "We":1, "Pu":2, "St":3, "Su":4};

  real d_l2r_ps;
  real d_r2l_ps; 
  bit l_internal_oe, r_internal_oe;

  bit[23:0] r_desc, l_desc, r_desc_dly, l_desc_dly, r_desc_inside, l_desc_inside;
  event l_stronger_drive_detected, r_stronger_drive_detected;

  initial {r_desc_dly,l_desc_dly} = {2{"HiZ"}};

  always @(r_desc_inside or l_desc_dly or r_stronger_drive_detected) 
    r_internal_oe <= oe_definition(l_desc_dly, r_desc, r_internal_oe);

  always @(l_desc_inside or r_desc_dly or l_stronger_drive_detected) 
    l_internal_oe <= oe_definition(r_desc_dly, l_desc, l_internal_oe);
  
  always @(l_desc_inside)
   l_desc_dly <= #(d_l2r_ps) l_desc_inside;

  always @(r_desc_inside)
    r_desc_dly <= #(d_r2l_ps) r_desc_inside;

  assign  r_desc_inside =  !r_internal_oe ? r_desc : "HiZ" ; 
  assign  l_desc_inside =  !l_internal_oe ? l_desc : "HiZ" ;

  always @(r_desc_dly[23:8] or l_desc[23:8])
    if((l_internal_oe == 1) & (r_desc_dly != l_desc))
      -> l_stronger_drive_detected;

  always @(l_desc_dly[23:8] or r_desc[23:8])
    if((r_internal_oe == 1) & (l_desc_dly != r_desc))
      -> r_stronger_drive_detected;

  always_comb if(en) $sformat(l_desc, "%v", l);
  always_comb if(en) $sformat(r_desc, "%v", r);

  via_strn_driver driver_l (r_desc_dly, l_internal_oe & en , l);
  via_strn_driver driver_r (l_desc_dly, r_internal_oe & en , r);

  function automatic bit oe_definition (bit[23:0] inside_desc, outside_desc, bit old_oe);
    oe_definition = inside_desc[23:8] == outside_desc[23:8] ? old_oe : 
      (assoc_strn2int[inside_desc[23:8]] > assoc_strn2int[outside_desc[23:8]]);
  endfunction

endmodule

module via_strn_driver(input bit [23:0] descr, bit en, output o);
  logic val ;
  always_comb begin
    case(descr[7:0])
      "1": val = 1'b1;
      "0": val = 1'b0;
      "X": val = 1'bx;
      "Z": val = 1'bz;
      default: $error(" Descr value is uncompatible with logic type"); 
    endcase  
  end

  assign (supply1,supply0) o = en ? ( descr[23:8] == "Su" ? val : 'z) : 'z;
  assign (strong1,strong0 )o = en ? ( descr[23:8] == "St" ? val : 'z) : 'z;
  assign (pull1,pull0)     o = en ? ( descr[23:8] == "Pu" ? val : 'z) : 'z;
  assign (weak1,weak0)     o = en ? ( descr[23:8] == "We" ? val : 'z) : 'z; 

endmodule
```

via_d module is able to transfer signal with the its strength.
The solution was checked on the vcs (synopsys) tool.
I hope my solution will be useful for your verification.

Comment: Nice work. Drive strength of the source nodes was not part of my original use case. It is not common to utilize Verilog strengths in typical RTL designs. I tested your code. There are fixable issues at time 0; (1) out of range warning in `oe_definition` (2) `$error` in `via_strn_driver`). I didn't see any resolution issues with standard unambiguous strengths. Further enhancements would be needed to support `large`,`medium`,`small` and ambiguous strengths (ex:`StH`,`SmL`,`651`,`56X`,etc). The only other challenge is it cannot be connected to another instance; my code has the same limitation.

Comment: 1: Thank you, Greg, for your attention to my solution. Drive strength of the source nodes was not part of my original use case too.  Your decision would be sufficient for my project. This enhanced task with strength has been bugging me. Therefore it is was my little interesting challenge in the vacation time. 2: I checked and fixed the bug: "(1).. warning in oe_definition (2) $error in via_strn_driver" and updated the code above. As for the rest of the strengths, I'm a little familiar with their use cases yet.  Maybe someday I'll add the support for the rest of the strength