# Assinging inout port to inout in both directions

Tags: verilog, inout

For simulation purposes, using Verilog, I would like to create a block that only has 2 inout ports (say left and right) and will be transmitting signals either from left to right or from right to left. It can be assumed that the block will be active only during the transition and will be waiting for inputs for the rest of the time. But I'm not allowed to use any other ports. So the module definition will be something like this in theory:

```
module blackbox(inout left, inout right)
  assign left = right;
  assign right = left;

  specify
    (left => (right:1'b1)) = 7;
    (right => (left:1'b1)) = 8;
  endspecify
endmodule
```

Is there a solution for this?

---

As a 2nd question, The problem can be simplified by determining the direction after the placement. For example, if the block placed in one location it will always transmit signal from left to right but in another location it can be from right to left. Would it be possible to somehow code this inside the module?

Thanks,

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820470/how-to-model-bidirectional-transport-delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Verilog

```
module blackbox(inout .left(internal), inout .right(internal));
 wire internal;
  specify
    (left => (right:1'b1)) = 7;
    (right => (left:1'b1)) = 8;
  endspecify
endmodule
```

or

```
 module blackbox(inout left, right);
     tran t(left,right); // some simulators might require this to work with specify block
      specify
        (left => (right:1'b1)) = 7;
        (right => (left:1'b1)) = 8;
      endspecify
    endmodule
```

In SystemVerilog:

```
 module blackbox(inout left, right)
   alias left = right;
      specify
        (left => (right:1'b1)) = 7;
        (right => (left:1'b1)) = 8;
      endspecify
 endmodule
```

For your second question, I'm not sure why you would need this for a simulation model, or how you would get placement information into the netlist.

Comment: The answer with "internal" wire gives syntax error in my case. Would it be simulator specific?
For the answer with "tran", it seems like it is working but delays are not reflected at all. Do you have any idea why it might be?
Thank you

Comment: The LRM does allow delay specifications on `tran` primitives, so I think it's extending that to specify blocks. The other solutions simply give two names to the same port. I don't know how you can model the delays for different directions other than putting the delays on the drivers.

Comment: Meant to say "does **not** allow delay specifications"

Comment: I know it's not the answer I'm looking for but I believe there might be none. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use tri-state signals, just like in real hardware:

```
assign A_inout = direction_is_A_to_B ? A_out : 1'bz;
assign B_inout = direction_is_A_to_B ? 1'bz  : B_out;
```

Then you can safely connect A_inout to B_inout;

The input is a copy of A_inout, but it may be clearer to explicitly use a signal:

```
assign A_in = A_inout;
```

Normally all that is done inside a bi-directional pad:

```
module bi_pad (
    inout  P,
    input  I,
    input  tri,
    output O
);

   assign P = tri ? 1'bz : O;
   assign I = P;

endmodule
```

---

You can use parameter to determine the direction but you must know when the block is instantiated which direction it must have. There is no feedback from e.g. a place & route tool to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but I was looking for a solution without tri-state buffers since I wouldn't know the value of "direction_is_A_to_B" and I don't have a pin for it.